# Android Studio - startActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

getch(); command is used in c++ to pause the program, What should i use in Android Studio to pause the program?

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if ((b[0].getText().toString()  == c && b[1].getText().toString()  == c && b[2].getText().toString()  == c) || (b[3].getText().toString()  == c && b[4].getText().toString()  == c && b[5].getText().toString()  == c) || (b[6].getText().toString()  == c && b[7].getText().toString()  == c && b[8].getText().toString()  == c) || (b[0].getText().toString()  == c && b[3].getText().toString()  == c && b[6].getText().toString()  == c) || (b[1].getText().toString()  == c && b[4].getText().toString()  == c && b[7].getText().toString()  == c) || (b[2].getText().toString()  == c && b[5].getText().toString()  == c && b[8].getText().toString()  == c) || (b[0].getText().toString()  == c && b[4].getText().toString()  == c && b[8].getText().toString()  == c) || (b[2].getText().toString()  == c && b[4].getText().toString()  == c && b[6].getText().toString()  == c)){
            if (c == "X"){
                paper.setText("You Won the Game.");


            }
            else{
                paper.setText("Computer Won the Game.");
            }
        }
```

I want to pause the program where i am displaying the result of the game using paper.setText(); command.

Comment: What does this question have to do with either Android Studio or `startActivity`? Android Studio is simply an IDE and your code doesn't show any attempt to start an `Activity`. Please rewrite your question to better explain what you are trying to achieve. Also, just as an aside, you can't compare strings using `==` in Java - you need to use the `equals(...)` method of the `String` class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside of an Activity simply call `this.finish();`

Edit: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it's typically not good practice to close the program without the user consenting to do so. After you have shown your text it may be better to show a dialog such as:
"Would you like to play again?"
 [Yes] [Close Game]

You can accomplish that with the following code:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Play again?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // start game over
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            MyActivity.this.finish(); 
//use the class name of you activity + this 
//to access your Activity's finish rather than try and perform finish on an onClick
        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.myicon)
     .show();
```